# Convert POJO with HashMap to XML

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have the following class which I want to convert to XML.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "counters" )
public class Counter {
    private Map<String, Integer> counter;
    
    public Counter(){}
     
    @XmlElement( name = "counter" )
    public Map<String, Integer> getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    
    public void setCounter(Map<String, Integer> counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}
```

I return an object of that class using GET request, however, I don't really like the response. Currently it looks like:

```
<counters>
    <counter>
        <entry>
            <key>admin</key>
            <value>10</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>user</key>
            <value>5</value>
        </entry>
    </counter>
</counters>
```

I'd like to have the response in the following format:

```
<counters>
    <counter>
        <user>admin</user>
        <number>10</number>
    </counter>
    <counter>
        <user>user</user>
        <n>5</value>
    </counter>
</counters>
```

Basically, I need to rename entry to counter, key to user, value to number.
Is it really possible with HashMap or do I need to change Counter class somehow to achieve my goal? I have already tried different Xml annotations but the response is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
public class Counter {
     private String user;
     private String number;
     //getters, setters
}
```

Add above counter in your root class as a List.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "counters" )
public class CounterInfo {
    private List<Counter> counter;
    //getters and setters
}
```